# Get state checkbox with xcuitest

Tags: swift, xcuitest

i want get state checkbox index 1 2 3 4

I have tried the below code but it doesn't seem to work

`app.checkBoxes.element(boundBy: 1)`

Can someone please tell what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the checkbox state, you can use this:

```
yourCheckbox.value as! String
```

If the checkbox is checked, the value is "1" ; otherwise the value is "0".